# Issue while reading a from container how do i put the data in sql table with this issue file

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

Error found when processing 'Csv/Tsv Format Text' source 'xyz_File' with row number 7: found more columns than expected column count: 65.. Activity ID:c310daeb-7c87-4176-95c3-47bab56a9b1b

I have tried with "\u0001" separator and it's providing only a single column.
Like Below.
col1,col2,col3......Col150

It should appear like.
col1,col2,col3......Col150==>>col1 Col2 col3

Answer (score 0):

Try defining the schemas in the copy activity.

Also next time you ask try to explain a bit more your case so we can help you in a better way.

Hope this helped!

Comment: You mean I need to write the schema manually. Can you explain little better.

Comment: Click on the copy activity, then on the lower window click "Mapping", then "Import Schemas". After that you can map columns from source to columns in the sink. This should solve your column errors.